# Multivariate polynomial regression

Tags: python, regression, multivariate-testing

I am trying to do a multivariate polynomial regression on my data in python. I have 4 independent and 1 dependent variable. I'm unsure even where to begin. I've gone through a lot of blogs in the last few days, but didn't get a lot of clarity. Most of the blogs are for univariate data. Is there a good post anywhere that anyone could direct me to, that explains the concept and has a sample code?
Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you make it more clear what your input and output are? Do you have a data set of `m` samples of dependent variables `xi[0],..,x[3]` with a corresponding set of `m` samples `yi` of the dependent variable for which you wish to fit a multivariate polynomial model (i.e., your output is the coefficients of the fitting polynomial)? Or is your problem different?

Answer (score 1):

scipy got an exelent solution here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

```
def defa(x, a,b,c,d):
    return a*b*c*d # the form for regresion you want to do
var1, var2 = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(defa,[x cordinates],[y cordinates])
print(var1)
# your a b c and d will ne printed out in order
```

btw incase your installing scipy for your first time now, you should know that scipy also requires you to have numpy :)

f.x.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def defa(x,a,b,c,d,e):
    return a**2+b**3+c**4+d**5+e
print(curve_fit(defa,range(1000),range(1000)))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(array([9.32720415, 4.0480121, 3.12719445, 2.49008364, 154.80388797]),array([...]))
```

this means that

```
a = 9.32720415
b = 4.0480121
c = 3.12719445
d = 2.49008364
e = 154.80388797
```

Comment: This does not seem like multivariate regression, there is only one variable (x) and a few constants (a-e).